# Show one word in tableviewcell at a time

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, reload

I am trying to show each word in a tableview cell with a 2 second pause between each word. Is this possible? I don't want to keep reloading modifying a cell and reloading it like this:

```
var fullNameArr = message.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
        var firstWord = true
        for word in fullNameArr {
            if firstWord {
                firstWord = false
             captionsArray.append(CaptionObject(isMacro:isMacro, number: numberToCall!.number, caption: word, time: String(describing:currentTimeInMiliseconds())))
                self.reloadTableAndScroll()
            } else {
                 let cap = self.captionsArray.last!
                cap.caption = cap.caption + " " + word
                captionsArray.remove(at: captionsArray.count)
                captionsArray.append(cap)
                self.reloadTableAndScroll()
            }


            self.reloadTableAndScroll()
        }
```

Comment: Run a timer every 2 seconds that displays the next cells text after the table finished loading. There's some finer details left out but maybe this could work for you

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Timer` to achieve this.

To create a `Timer`, just declare your timer variable at the top of your class, and initialize it in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
var timer: Timer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(addWordCell), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    // ...
}
```

Now every 2 seconds, your `addWordCell` method will be called.
By the way, I suggest you using the `insertsRows` method instead of reloading your table view all the time, it will be way more efficient. For example you could write your `addWordCell` method like this:

```
var words = [String]()

var currentWordIndex = 0

let sentence = "Hello how are you doing today?"

func addWordCell() {

    let wordsArray = sentence.components(separatedBy: " ").map({ $0 })

    guard currentWordIndex < wordsArray.count else {
        return
    }

    words.append(wordsArray[currentWordIndex])

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: words.count-1, section: 0)], with: .fade)
    tableView.endUpdates()

    currentWordIndex += 1
}
```

And you would of course need to change your table view data source methods:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return words.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = words[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Now if you want to add a nice little fading effect whenever a new cell appear, you could use the `willDisplayCell` method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    cell.alpha = 0.0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: {

        cell.alpha = 1.0
    })
}
```

That's it! Obviously you could improve the code even more, and custom it to fit your needs, but at least this should give you a little working example showing a possible approach.